# Barcode not generated in C# web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am trying for create a barcode in my web form.for that i download font **IDAutomationHC39M** and install in my system,then i run my wesite in localhost but barcode cannot be generated.This is my code

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string barCode = TextBox1.Text;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 40, 80))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
                Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
                graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
            }
            plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
        }
```

And the result is appear like that *code*

Comment: It would be helpful if you can describe in more detail what the problem is, perhaps attach the output image?

Comment: when i give a string ABCD123 as input ,then i got the barcode as 

*ABCD123*

Comment: Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 16);
This code does not work

Comment: Is the Font available to the WPF process that is running? Meaning: you may need full trust to see the font store on the machine - and perhaps WPF is picking the next best fit which, to be honest, is probably nothing like the barcode you are after!